# Cannot find items in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hy to all,
I have a problem with some code that throws no error but doesn't work indeed.
I have an Ajax call like this:

```
function getroleitems(ruolo){
fun = new Array();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {id: ruolo},
url: "getroleitems.php",
success: function(data){
    fun = data;
    console.log(fun);
    for (var i=0;i<44;i++){

    if(fun.indexOf("i")>-1){
        alert('trovato '+i);
        $('#'+i).attr('checked', true);
    }
    }
},dataType:"json"
});
```

This get from a db an array of numbers (only some of all the numbers between 1 and 43). An example is this: ["0", "27", "31", "30", "32", "33", "8", "29", "19", "42"].
The point is that I can't get to evaluate this array against all the numbers between 1 and 43 (the for loop) since the if inside the for loop never evaluates true. I have tried both $.inArray and indexOf without any luck.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance
Lelio

Comment: `"i"` is a string. It will never be found among digits.

Comment: You're looking for the literal string `"i"` in the array, not its value... on top of that your server returns an array of *numeric strings*, not an array of *numbers*.

Comment: This was the last of many test. I had to pass it as i.toString() to turn each i to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the loop entirely by making use of `,` in selectors.

```
if (fun.length) // only do this if there is something to do
    $('#' + fun.join(', #')).attr('checked', true);
```

Furthermore it may be worth noting that beginning an *id* with a character other than *a-z* may give unexpected results, even though it is permitted in the *HTML5* spec. You may want to prefix a letter before the number part.

Answer (score 1):

Change `fun.indexOf("i")` to `fun.indexOf(''+i)`

Answer (score 0):

`if(fun.indexOf("i")>-1){`

your "i" is between double quote and not considered as a variable what if you try this instead:
`if(fun.indexOf(''+i)>-1){`

Comment: `["1"].indexOf(1) === -1`, `i` needs to be passed as a _String_, i.e. `''+i`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
fun.each( function ( i ) {
    $( '#' + i ).attr( 'checked' , true );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it will work:

```
function getroleitems(ruolo){
fun = new Array();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {id: ruolo},
url: "getroleitems.php",
success: function(data){
    fun = data;
    console.log(fun);
    for (var i=0;i<44;i++){

    if(fun.indexOf(i.toString())>-1){
        alert('trovato '+i);
        $('#'+i).attr('checked', true);
    }
    }
},dataType:"json"
});
```

I have changed "i" to i.toString() in your if condition